# android java MultiKeyMap not recognising decorate() despite documentation

Tags: java, android, eclipse, apache-commons

Hi can anyone shed light onto why this code does not work in eclipse? The documentation clearly states this should work - the imports are working fine - the code will run but the MultKeyMap is unordered - which I really hate

```
import org.apache.commons.collections4.map.LinkedMap;
import org.apache.commons.collections4.map.MultiKeyMap;

private MultiKeyMap Before = new MultiKeyMap(); //works
private MultiKeyMap Before = MultiKeyMap.decorate(new LinkedMap()) //doesn't work
```

Answer (score 0):

this was fixed by not using "org.apache.commons.collections4.map" but merely using "org.apache.commons.collections.map" i.e. downloading [3.2.1](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/download_collections.cgi) not 4.4.0

**EDIT:** it appears collections4 is a *substantial* rewrite involving non-raw types (good!) but the internet is absent of any code examples whatsoever, if anyone has an example of using MultiKeyMaps typed to non-raw types *AND* using decoration I am all ears!

Answer (score 0):

*I know its an old question but i found myself facing this same issue so I decided to share the solution :)*

Looking at the [docs](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/map/MultiKeyMap.html) they are using a different method: `multiKeyMap` and not `decorate`

```
private MultiKeyMap cache = MultiKeyMap.multiKeyMap(new LRUMap(50));
```

This is working fine for me.